# Read multiple strings input using fgets()

Tags: c++, string

I need to

1. Take a command line argument giving number of strings (say `N`).
2. Call a function to take `N` input lines from user (using `fgets`)
3. Store them in an array of pointers.
   i.e. `char *input_lines[MAX_LINES];`
4. All newlines from the lines should be removed

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this kind of questions ("write this code for me"-like) are generally discouraged here. You should try something yourself and ask about specific problems you have faced, not require others to do you work for you. Best regards.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].